# Calculated field starting with external variable

Tags: sql

I have a table Tbl1 with fields : description, Dtype, valueLeft, valueRight
The data maybe like this :

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| Description | Dtype | valueLeft | valueRight |
+----------------------------------------------+
| Art1        |   1   |     5     |       0    |
| Art2        |   1   |     3     |       0    |
| Art3        |   2   |     0     |       6    |
| Art4        |   1   |     11    |       0    |
| Art5        |   2   |     0     |       1    |
| ArtN        | ....  |    ....   |      ....  |
+..............................................+
```

Field Dtype only can be 1 or 2

Question : I want to do a SELECT with new column that SUM valueLeft OR valueRight depending of value on field Dtype (1=sum valueLeft , 2=deduct valueRight)

Example :

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| Description | Dtype | valueLeft | valueRight | newcol
+----------------------------------------------+
| Art1        |   1   |     5     |       0    |    5
| Art2        |   1   |     3     |       0    |    8
| Art3        |   2   |     0     |       6    |    2
| Art4        |   1   |     11    |       0    |    13
| Art5        |   2   |     0     |       1    |    10
```

How can I Do it?

Comment: why? what have you tried?

Comment: what `rdbms` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify RDBMS... using `SQL Server` syntax:

```
SELECT a.Description, a.Dtype, a.valueLeft, a.valueRight, 
            (SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN b.Dtype = 1 THEN b.valueLeft ELSE -b.valueRight END)
             FROM (
                    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Description) as id, Dtype, valueLeft, valueRight 
                    FROM Tbl1 ) b
             WHERE b.id <= a.id)
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Description) as id,  Description, Dtype, valueLeft, valueRight 
      FROM Tbl1 ) a
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89336/16)